# Append string element from class to array of strings

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have `class` in which have variable `hall` and other variables. I need to need pull out and add variable `hall` in new array of strings.

All variables are now stored in a variable with type `BookingHall`.

How do I get and add a variable `hall` to a new variable?

For everything I use `firestore`.

My class implementation:

```
protocol BookingDocumentSerializable {

    init?(dictionary: [String:Any])

}

struct BookingHall {

    var contactInfo: [String: Any] = [:]
    ................
    var hall: String = ""

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {

        return [

            "contact_info": contactInfo,
            ................
            "hall": hall

        ]
    }
}

extension BookingHall: BookingDocumentSerializable {

    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {

        let contactInfo = dictionary["contact_info"] as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
        ................
        let hall = dictionary["hall"] as? String ?? ""

        self.init(contactInfo: contactInfo,
                  ................
                  hall: hall)

    }
}
```

Here i get all variable in class:

```
var hallArray: [String] = []

private var historyBooking: [BookingHall] = []

fileprivate func observeQuery() {

    guard let query = query else { return }

    listener = query.addSnapshotListener { [unowned self] (snapshot, error) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot {

            let bookingModel = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> BookingHall in

                if let newHistoryBooking = BookingHall(dictionary: document.data()) {

                    return newHistoryBooking

                } else {

                    fatalError("Ошибка загрузки!")

                }
            }

            self.historyBooking = bookingModel
            self.document = snapshot.documents

            for index in 0...self.historyBooking.count {

                self.hallArray.append(self.historyBooking[index].hall)

                print("hall id \(self.hallArray)")

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

In here I get error `index out of range`, but in console I can see `hall id`.

```
self.hallArray.append(self.historyBooking[index].hall)
```

How do I correctly add `hall` to a new array of strings in...

```
var hallArray: [String] = []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very common mistake.

Indexes are zero-based. Imagine your array has one element. The range `0...array.count` has the indexes `0` and `1` but there is no element at index 1...

---

You have to write either

```
for index in 0..<self.historyBooking.count
```

or

```
for index in 0...self.historyBooking.count - 1
```

The first syntax is preferable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I hope now I will no longer get this error.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `Index out of bound` you can use `for...in` loop

```
for obj in 0...self.historyBooking.count {

  self.hallArray.append(obj.hall)

  print("hall id \(self.hallArray)")

}
```